# Passing data through Higher-Order-Functions

Tags: haskell

I've been having this problem a lot recently in some form or another. Lets say that I want to take a number x and apply a bunch of high order functions to x producing y. I then check to see if y satisfies a certain property, if it does, then I want to return x.

This problem seems to get really tricky when I have a list of numbers [x1,x2..xn] and the functions I apply condense the list. For example, I apply a function to each of the elements in the list (producing [y1,y2..]), sort, group, and then I want to return the values of x for the largest group. For example:

```
head . reverse . sort . map (length) . group . sort . map (mod 4) $ [1..10]
```

The answer is 6, but how would I rewrite a function like this to tell me which elements numbers 1 through 10 belong to those 6?

I've played with the idea of passing tuples and using fst everywhere until the snd is required, or writing a new class to make it so something like sort only works on one element of the class, but I can't seem to come up with a clean approach

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a small set of changes to your code that return the value rather than the length; the use of the *`By` functions avoids the need to use tuples:

```
maximumBy (compare `on` length) . groupBy ((==) `on` mod 4) . sortBy (compare `on` mod 4) $ [1..10]
```

This code requires Data.List and Data.Function.  Data.Function includes `on`, which allows a comparison (for sorting or grouping) to be applied to some function of the input.

Comment: Thanks, this looks a lot cleaner than what I would have come up with. I'm starting to understand that there's no general approach to problems like these.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in GHC's [`TransformListComp` extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#generalised-list-comprehensions), which enables a direct way to express your query.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TransformListComp #-}
import GHC.Exts

input = [1..10]
output = [ x
         | x <- input
         , let y = 4 `mod` x
         , then group by y
         , then sortWith by (-length x, the y)
         ]
-- output = [[5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,4],[3]]
```

Comment: I didn't know that extension existed, looks interesting, I'll start playing with it